# OpenCV didn't work in Python virtual env on Archlinux

Tags: python, opencv, archlinux

I have installed `opencv` by the follow commands:

```sh
sudo pacman -Sy opencv python-opencv hdf5 vtk
```

After this, I can use `opencv` normally in the system python and C++ environment, but `opencv` didn't work when I create a new virtual environment.

I installed `opencv-python` and `numpy` by `pip` , and I tried to run a sample program using python in a virtual environment:

```py
import cv2

img = cv2.imread("./001.jpg")
cv2.imshow("outuput", img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

it tells me:

```sh
segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

if I run this demo without using a virtual environment, everything is normal, and the image will be output normally.

But I didn't install the pip package `opencv-python` in system python environment.

**I want to know how opencv works with python ? and how to make it work in a virtual environment?**